# Forcing Windows 2008 Server sysprep to ask for a new product key

Tags: windows-server-2008, sysprep

I'm trying to create a Windows Server 2008 Image that will prompt for a new product ID on startup.

Is there a way to force 'sysprep' to clear the current product key and require the user to enter a new product key?

Unfortunately we don't know the product key the user of the image is going to use, so it can't be included in the unattended.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirror the last answer. You should install a base windows 2008 OS and not licence it in any way shape or form and then create your image. You should get 60 days grace from day of install anyway.

You can then enter a product key of your choice once you create the new server from the image.

Comment: To follow up, you have a couple tries at re-arming.  If you already armed the thing, just run `cscript \Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /rearm`.  I think you get like 3 rearms anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, but.... you can always set up your image with the default KMS key (that is public, btw).... then the new Windows behaves like the old one, which is starting in KMS mode.

2008 Server per default does not ask for a key.

Comment: +1, He can also include the key in the unattend file.